# Unable to Integrate React-Native in Android App

Tags: android, react-native

I have a android App which uses Webkit for rendering the Web Pages. I have 
*Editor.html* File (which is written in html, javascript and css). It uses the android webkit interface to communicate between JavaScript and the Native Code.

Now I want to use React-Native in my app for Communicating between Native code and Js code.

To integrate React-Native in my app, I am using this blog:
[Medium Blog for Integrating React Native](https://medium.com/mindorks/react-native-integration-with-existing-app-f2757c2e672d)

As I am adding below the code in the my build.gradle.

*Code:*

```
maven {
    url "<PATH TO YOUR ROOT DIRECTORY>/AwesomeApp/node_modules/react-native/android"
}
```

I am getting the following error.

*Error:*

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_height' with value '@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size').

Message{kind=ERROR, text=No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_height' with value 
'@dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size')., sources=[/Users/././android/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_add__audio.xml:18:32-71], original message=, tool name=Optional.of(AAPT)}
```

Due to this error, some values specified in the dimension file are not accessible to the layout file.

*android/build.gradle:*

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url "/Users/../node_modules/react-native/android"
        }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


targetSdkVersion: 26
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Can you post the whole content of your `android/build.gradle` file?

Comment: those Gradle plugins are hopelessly outdated ...

Answer (score 0):

the dimension resource it cannot find: `dimen/abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size` hints for lacking a dependency ...because that's where it comes from:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.support/appcompat-v7
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
```

or this one:

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.appcompat/appcompat
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2"
```

Comment: My app currently targets to Android Sdk Version: 26. Should i update the target version?

Comment: @VivekSharma if that `react-native:0.58.6` came from the local maven repository and it cannot find it - revert that change, because that might indeed be a maven repository. React is altogether a little crappy, because it should ordinary be fetched from `jitpack.io` (alike everybody else distributes their packages). the `targetSdkVersion` does not matter too much, but update the Gradle plugins; `gradle:2.2.0` should be `gradle:3.3.1` and `google-services:3.2.1` should be `google-services:4.2.0`. adding the missing `appcompat` library as dependency should provide the missing dimension resource.

Comment: @VivekSharma "didn't work" is not an error description. `abc_action_bar_progress_bar_size` definitely comes from there; you might have to sync the project in order to download that dependency - or just substitute it with any value (without having looked up it's actual value), but alike `16dp`.

Comment: Making the specified changes in the gradle worked for me. I also had to upgrade my CompileSdkVersion and TargetSdkVersion to 28.